# How to create a datagridview from another one?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I use visual studio 2012: c# winform. I have a `datagridview` in which 2 columns(Id and society) are created. the `datagridview` contains 25 records fetched my database.

I also added a button named "Action" to each row in `datagridview`
Note: In my `phpmyadmin` database, each society contains many service category and service types

**My problem is:**

I want that when a button "action" is pressed, all the service category and service type related to that society appear in the same or another `datagridview`.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try somthing like that, you must initiate this function with your main DataGridView, and you will have your "Cloned" DataGridView.

```
public DataGridView CloneDataGrid(DataGridView mainDataGridView)
{
    DataGridView cloneDataGridView = new DataGridView();

        if (cloneDataGridView.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn datagrid in mainDataGridView.Columns)
            {
                cloneDataGridView.Columns.Add(datagrid.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
            }
        }

        DataGridViewRow dataRow = new DataGridViewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < mainDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dataRow = (DataGridViewRow)mainDataGridView.Rows[i].Clone();
            int Index = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in mainDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells)
            {
                dataRow.Cells[Index].Value = cell.Value;
                Index++;
            }
            cloneDataGridView.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        cloneDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        cloneDataGridView.Refresh();


    return cloneDataGridView;
}
```

Hope This Help

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, you could use a cell content click event to refill your datatable with the filtered results.

I've done this on one of my forms (see below), however I havent used a phpmyadmin database, only sql, but the logic might be the same.

I should also note that I have the default cell selection as full row select.

For arguments sake, let's say the form shows products, so ProductID, ProductName and ProductType. When we click the button in the grid we want it to filter by the selected row's ProductType.

```
//First we declare a static string that can be accessed by the whole form
//and blank it so the form doesnt use a previous value.
public static string product_type = ""

//In the form load event, the gridview is populated - this could be moved to anywhere.
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("DB connection string");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sqlDataAdap.Fill(ds);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sqlDataAdap.Fill(dt);
    conn.Close();
}

//In the cell contect click event we give it the ProductType 
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Here we declare a var to identify that we're looking at the row
    var row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells;
    //Now we set the string we declared earlier
    product_type = Convert.ToString(row["ProductType"].Value);

    //Now we repeat the grid script with a parameter which uses our string from above
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("DB connection string");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductType = @ProductType", conn);
    sc.Parameters.Add("@ProductType", SqlDbType.Int).Value = product_type;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sqlDataAdap.Fill(ds);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sqlDataAdap.Fill(dt);
    conn.Close();
}
```

You could then just add a button which repeats the script from the form load event when clicked to return the grid to it's non-filtered state.

Hope this helps.